# Build table dynamically using model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello everyone I have this mark up:

```
 table: {           
     columns: [
          {
             header: "Col 1",
             rows: [
                     1,2
                   ]
          },
          {
             header: "Col 2",
               rows: [
                        5,6
                     ]
           },
           {
             header: "Col 3",
               rows: [
                      3,4
                     ]
           }
       ]
   }
```

I would like to use angularjs to build a table like this:

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-ng-repeat="col in table.columns">{{col.header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="col in table.columns">
      <td data-ng-repeat="row in col.rows">{{row}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to get the result like this:

Col 1       Col 2       Col 3

1             5           3

2             6           4

However, the code above doesn't produce that result. I don't mind changing the structure of the data if there is a better way to do this. The only requirement is that if I remove one column, all the rows belonging to that column need to go as well. Thanks

Comment: `table.columns[0].rows.map((v, i) => table.columns.map(c => c.rows[i]))` will create this: `[[1, 5, 3], [2, 6, 4]]`

Comment: @ChrisG could you explain a bit more how I could implement that on my html mark up above <td data-ng-repeat="row in col.rows">{{row}}</td>? I used number just as an example. Any data can be in each cell.

Comment: The above expression returns a new array. You need to put that in your `scope` as, say, `trs`, then use `tds in trs` and `td in tds` and `{{td}}`

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will try that. But I imagine I will have issue when I delete a column. Perhaps I can just generate the new array again. Hope there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the data as you have it, and use the two functions below to obtain the rows and modify the template to use the getRows() function, please note that the code considers that you always have at least one column:

```js
function getRows(){
    let rows = new Array<Array<number>>();
    for (let i = 0; i<this.table.columns[0].rows.length; i++) {
        rows.push(getRow(i));
    }
    return row;
}

function getRow(index){
    let row = new Array<number>();
    for (let column of this.table.columns) {
        row.push(column.rows[index];
    }
    return row;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-ng-repeat="col in table.columns">{{col.header}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="row in getRows()">
          <td data-ng-repeat="value in row">{{row}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about doing that too. But the problem is when I remove a column, how could I remove the rows belonging to that column too because now they are in different arrays?

Comment: Maybe I could do it by using the index of the column. But I still think if the columns can hold their own rows and when I remove the columns, all their rows are gone too. Wouldn't that be better?

Comment: I understood the columns requirement now, so I changed the code. I did not run the code, but the idea is to convert the data structure to obtain the rows from the table.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't work for me. The functions have a lot of syntax errors.